# Browserify - keep comments?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm using browserify to take a source that just has a few require statements, which the output file I will use in a library.

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
require("gl-state");
require("glslify");
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

Problem is the jshint ignore comments get dropped when i browserify this file. Is there a way to keep them around?

Comment: When compiling using the `-d` option for sourcemaps, comments are left intact with the version of browserify(5.9.1) i'm using, although this behavior is not specifically documented.

Comment: That did keep the comments, problem is i need them around the whole file. Due to linting the compile library.js. Might just have to do a task to manually insert them. Thanks though :)

Comment: Ended up using https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-file-append to add the comments, but feel free to submit your answer for me to accept, as it was correct, just not what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling using the `-d` option for *sourcemaps*, comments are left intact in  browserify (using version `5.9.1`).

However this behavior seems not to be specifically documented.